# Line Renderer is not appear on camera using vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to create AR of these lines. A room acoustic simulation.

[image]

I'm really noobie to unity as well as AR stuff so I tried to create these line using Line Renderer first.
Here is what I have done on unity3D

[image]

I haven't use script yet because I have completely no idea how to do it.

So when I tried this on the camera, only the cube was shown, no sign of these lines appearing at all. Anyone have any idea about how to solve this? Thank you.

Update: My LineRenderer setting.
[image]
This is all the same for each line renderer, the differences are just the number on x,y and z.

Comment: Could you show us the linerenderer in Unity, it is possible that your lines are just too thin to be seen.

Comment: Sure, I'll update it.

Comment: @TimLepage I tried thicken the line but still not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unchecking the "use world space" option and place it manually in the environment.